# Xamarin error System.DllNotFoundException: /system/lib/libsqlite.so on Android 7.0

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, sqlite-net, android-7.0-nougat

I get this exception whenever I try to create a SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection in android 7.0
any idea how to fix it?
I'm using these nuget pacakges:

```
<packages>
  <package id="ExifLib.PCL" version="1.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid6" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl" version="1.1.10" targetFramework="monoandroid43" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.21" targetFramework="monoandroid43" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="7.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid6" />
  <package id="SQLite.Net.Core-PCL" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="monoandroid6" />
  <package id="SQLite.Net-PCL" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="monoandroid6" />
  <package id="SQLiteNetExtensions" version="1.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios1" />
  <package id="sqlite-net-pcl" version="1.2.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="SQLitePCL.bundle_green" version="0.9.3" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="SQLitePCL.plugin.sqlite3.android" version="0.9.3" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="SQLitePCL.raw" version="0.9.3" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green" version="1.1.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="SQLitePCLRaw.core" version="1.1.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3.android" version="1.1.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3.android" version="1.1.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="Xam.Plugins.Settings" version="2.5.1.0" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Design" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.FFImageLoading" version="2.2.5" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Forms" version="2.2.5" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Forms" version="2.3.3.168" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads" version="29.0.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Analytics" version="29.0.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.AppIndexing" version="29.0.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base" version="29.0.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement" version="29.0.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Insights" version="1.12.3" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
</packages>
```

Comment: Does it runs well in android 6.0 or other version?

Comment: no, actually the fix for me was to compile using the older build tools for android 6 and the crash disappeared on android 7 as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for me was to update the SQLiteNetExtensions nuget package to the latest Alpha version (prerelease), it's important to first remove all references to sqlite related libs though.

Comment: What was the version number?

Comment: installing version 2.0.0-alpha2 fixed the problem

Comment: Installing  2.0.0-alpha2 version of SQLiteNetExtensions nuget package didn't help me. Still get the same exception when create SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection.

Comment: it's important to first remove all references to sqlite related libs in your solution, before installing the new version. you  did that?

Comment: It should be work in PCL project too? I have the same problem

Comment: I guess so, since xamarin projects are pcl as well, but try the solution for yourself to make sure

Comment: You have saved my life.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are using [oystein.krog package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Net-PCL/)
You should try with [praeclarum package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/)

Comment: After several tries, you pointed me to the solution : the use of sqlite-net-pcl did the trick for me. Thank you !

Comment: Upgraded to 8.1 Oreo within Xamarin, got system dllnotfound /system/lib/libsqlite.so exception. removed SQLite , installed pcl package Install-Package sqlite-net-pcl -Version 1.5.231 - error resolved. Thanks

Comment: I've been all day reading forums about that same issue until right now!! Thank you so much Alessandro !! It solved my issue too :)

Answer (score 0):

i have same issue in my xamarin android. [i install this package for sqlite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/data-access/using-sqlite-orm) and set targeted version to android 8(oreo) my application works again