# C# Xamarin SQLite missing system.dll

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, xamarin

HELP, I get an error at this line:

```
var r = SQLite3.Open (databasePathAsBytes, out handle, (int) openFlags, IntPtr.Zero);
```

System.DllNotFoundException:  occurred

what can I do?

Comment: Add a reference to mono.data.sqliteclient to your project.

Comment: which reference do I need to add?

Comment: Where can I find mono.data.sqliteclient, because it's not a nuget package or reference

Comment: I've never used it myself, but what about this one: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mono.Data.Sqlite.Portable/

Comment: Try adding this nuget package "SQLite.Net-PCL"

Comment: Installed it, still nothing!

Comment: In many occasion you may need to **clean solution - close VS - delete bin and obj - start VS back** You may also need to delete the **Package** folder before starting VS back

Comment: What if it gets broken!

Comment: That folders are generated while you are coding or debugging. bin and obj are in your project folder as same as Package which is in the solution folder. When you will restart VS it will **restaure** the packages and **regenerate** the files in the **obj** folder

Comment: still gives an error!

Comment: You could refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40930643/xamarin-error-system-dllnotfoundexception-system-lib-libsqlite-so-on-android-7)