# Xamarin.Forms Shared Project: System.DllNotFoundException: /system/lib/libsqlite.so

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms, sqlite-net

I have been using the SQLite.cs and SQLiteAsync.cs classes in my Shared Poject for over a year without issue. However, Google now requires that you set Android projects with a target of at least 8.0 (26) when uploading apps to Google Play. Setting the target version to 26 is causing the SQLite.cs and SQLiteAsync.cs classes to no longer work in my app. Any SQLite operations result in the following error:

```
System.DllNotFoundException: /system/lib/libsqlite.so
```

The well-documented solution for this is to either set target to below 26 (no longer feasible), or to update the sqlite-net-pcl nuget, as per these posts:

[Xamarin error System.DllNotFoundException: /system/lib/libsqlite.so on Android 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40930643/xamarin-error-system-dllnotfoundexception-system-lib-libsqlite-so-on-android-7)

[System.DllNotFoundException: /system/lib/libsqlite.so- Xamarin Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52052631/system-dllnotfoundexception-system-lib-libsqlite-so-xamarin-forms)

However, this only applies to PCL projects. Does anyone know of a fix for Shared Projects?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System.DllNotFoundException: /system/lib/libsqlite.so- Xamarin Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52052631/system-dllnotfoundexception-system-lib-libsqlite-so-xamarin-forms)

Comment: I don't think that is a solution to my problem. My Xamarin.forms project is a shared project, NOT a PCL project, as I made very clear in my original question.